# can infinite cont frac converge to rational

Tags: continued-fractions

Unsure whether question already answered - there are over 1000 questions on this forum with the "continued-fractions" string.

I request a proof (or hints) that an infinite continued fraction can not converge to a rational number.  Using http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2008/REUPapers/Yang.pdf as a reference, I followed pages 1-7 (through theorem 1.19), but can not determine how to use the referenced theorems 1.16 or 1.19 to create the desired proof.

Note: I am aware that all rational numbers have a (unique) finite continued fraction, as discussed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction.  However, I don't think that the Euclidean Algorithm eliminates the possibility of an infinite continued fraction converging to a rational number.

Comment: The convergents of the continued fraction for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^+$ are the best rational approximations of the number, in the sense that any better approximation has a larger denominator when written as a fraction. You can't have a better approximation than equality.

Comment: Also, this isn't twitter. You can use full words in your title.....

Comment: It's important that it is a simple continued fraction. An infinite general continued fraction can definitely converge to a rational.

Comment: to law-of-fives thanks for the specification.  to user296602 although your comment seems intuitively reasonable, I don't understand how to turn this into  a formal proof.  Also, I looked at the bottom of https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/contfrac/converge.html, but that reasoning compared (p/q), a convergent of _the_ finite continued fraction with (p_n/q_n), a convergent in the (mythical) infinite convergent fraction.  This seems invalid to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next day, better mood. [Khinchin does, indeed, do a better job](http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/Continued%20Fractions%20Khinchin.pdf). Theorem 11 on page 12 says, with the $a_0; a_1, a_2,...$ (positive) integers, all convergents $p/q$ are irreducible, that is $\gcd(p,q)=1.$ **ASSUME** the limiting value of an infinite (simple) continued fraction is rational $m/n$ with $\gcd(m,n) = 1.$

Theorem 9 on page 9 says  $$ \left| \frac{m}{n} - \frac{p}{q} \right| < \frac{1}{q^2} \; \; ,  $$
since the apparatus has $q_{k+1} > q_k.$

Your continued fraction is infinite, which means we can take a convergent far enough out so that
$$  q > n \; \; . $$
Then
  $$ \left| \frac{m}{n} - \frac{p}{q} \right| = \left| \frac{mq-np}{nq}  \right| < \frac{1}{q^2} \; \; . $$
In turn, this says
$$ |mq-np| < \frac{nq}{q^2} = \frac{n}{q} < 1. $$
As $|mq-np|$ is a non-negative integer, we find
$$   mq=np.  $$
As $\gcd(p,q) = 1,$ it follows that
$$  q | n \; \; .  $$
However, this contradicts $q > n,$ then contradicts the assumption that the limit of the infinite continued fraction is a rational number.

Comment: wow.  i'm going to flag, requesting that you be given more points.  i was frustrated because i had looked at 6 different cont frac sources, the REU pdf seemed the best of the 6, and I didn't want to start over with Khinchin.  Through thm 11 of the Khinchin pdf, it seems great.